# Javascript IDE with code completion and syntax checking

Tags: javascript, software-development, ide, autocomplete

Please suggest an IDE for JavaScript Coding with code completion and syntax checking for Windows or Linux.

So far I have found that **satisfactory code completion and syntax checking** support of JavaScript is provided by:

- Visual Studio
- Cloud9 IDE

*This list is not exhaustive, but based on what I have already used.*

But the code completion and syntax checking is far from perfect. It only provides suggestions based on what is already used.

**Please suggest an IDE for JavaScript that has good code completion and syntax checking.**

---

I know JavaScript is a loosely typed language and thus, a perfect code completion and syntax checking is very unlikely. So please share your experience about what IDE you felt comfortable in.

I find Cloud9 IDE satisfactory for JavaScript. But I miss the Intellisense that I get when coding C# in Visual Studio.

Comment: IntelliSense is one **major** reason to use VS.

Answer (score 12):

If you miss mandatory tools for a JavaScript developer then why don't you try `NetBeans`, a tool with syntax coloring and code completion support, including support for modern  JavaScript frameworks like jQuery, JSON, Knockout, Ext Js, AngularJS, JsDoc, ExtDoc, and ScriptDoc.

The images below are focused on those features you specified:

[image: NetBeans IDE 7.4 working with an HTML file]

[image: NetBeans IDE 7.4 working with autocomplete in action]

Don't miss these articles, also:

- http://kowsheek.com/2013/04/21/html-css-js-development-in-netbeans/
- http://www.sitepoint.com/netbeans-73-html5-support/
- http://www.oio.de/public/opensource/comparison-IDE-for-HTML5-CSS3-JavaScript-shootout.htm

Answer (score 7):

Take a look into JetBrains WebStorm. It's a fully focused IDE for web development, and is full of modules and plugins for develop JS using the most commons frameworks, like Angular, etc.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on *why* this particular IDE fulfils the needs raised in the question?

Comment: This got 6 upvotes already. i would upvote it too, as I agree that it is a good match - BUT, I won't until the answer is edited to provide much more information as to why it is such a good match. Welcome aboard, but please read [answer]. I don't mean to be rude here, just to encourage good quality answers which will help others who read the question in future.

Answer (score 6):

## [Brackets](http://brackets.io/)

I started using it a few days ago -- so far, so good. 
It's more focused on the front-end, but it has extensions to work with node.js in the back-end too. Some of its selling points (from its webpage):

- #### Live HTML Development

  As you code, HTML changes are instantly pushed to browser without having to save or reload the page.
- #### JS Debugging with Theseus

  Theseus makes inspecting variables and control flow easy, even in asynchronous code.
- #### Replace across multiple files

  Replace in Files shows all search matches first and you can uncheck any you don't wish to replace. Supports the same exclusion filtering as Find in Files.
- #### JavaScript Code Hinting Crash Prevention

  Brackets automatically stops processing problematic JavaScript files that previously could cause a crash.

Comment: I can heartily recommend brackets. Not just for JS, but also for AngularJS (I haven't found better for Angular). Check out the live preview feature where change sin code (and CSS) are instantly reflected in the browser, with no file saving needed.

Answer (score 5):

### [**Visual Studio Code**](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

- **IntelliSense** provides smart completions based on variable types, function definitions, and imported modules.
- **Debugging** Launch or attach to your running apps and debug with break points, call stacks, and an interactive console.
- **Extensible** A large variety of plugins (for syntax checking by example)

Answer (score 4):

There's four that I found that has awesome autocomplete:

1. JetBrain's [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) (commercial)
2. Adobe's [Brackets](http://brackets.io) (free, it uses [TernJS](http://ternjs.net), the most awesome autocomplete library)
3. [Atom.io](http://atom.io) (it has [ternjs](https://github.com/artoale/atom-tern) plugin also)
4. SublimeText (it has [ternjs](https://github.com/marijnh/tern_for_sublime) [plugin](https://github.com/emmetio/sublime-tern) also)
5. **BONUS** [NodeClipse/EnideStudio](http://www.nodeclipse.org/) never tried it though, but from the [screenshot](http://www.nodeclipse.org/enide/studio/2014/) looks awesome

all of them has syntax checking plugin (jslint, etc). But the one with best built-in syntax checking and autocomplete would be WebStorm.